# The computer hangs when debugging an ASP.NET webform

Tags: asp.net

I start learning ASP.NET few days. I don't know why my computer hangs when I debug my very simple application? My computer hangs, not only IDE hangs? Please help me!

Comment: Please provide more details - OS, version of Visual Studio, version of IIS.

Comment: My OS is Windows Vista Home Premium 64 bit, Visual Studio 2010 RC, .NET Framework 4, IIS 7... I'm learning about Server Control, using Toolbox in VS. I create a web form to implement examples. There are many web forms in my project. I debug and run, then stop debugging, add code, and then debug and run.. about 10 times. And then computer hangs.. :(( help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the application added as a virtual directory to IIS?  Maybe adding the application to IIS will help remedy it if you are using the local web server.  Also, try checking the application log in the event viewer for any error statements, see if the tool you are using is logging errors.

We need more info about what IDE you are using, the .NET framework version?

Comment: My OS is Windows Vista Home Premium 64 bit, Visual Studio 2010 RC, .NET Framework 4, IIS 7... I'm learning about Server Control, using Toolbox in VS. I create a web form to implement examples.There are many web forms in my project. I debug and run, then stop debugging, add code, and then debug and run... about 10 times. And then computer hangs..
I don't know how to add my app as a virtual directory to IIS. Please tell me. Thanks. And please tell me how to check app log in the event viewer. Thanks so much. I'm beginner.^^

Comment: Event Viewer is in your Administrative Tools folder; sometimes checking for errors there will help you figure it out.  Also, something you may want to check; after the stop and start for a while, you will want to check the task manager (ctrl + alt + delete > task manager) and in the processes tab, order by ram usage.  It may be the local web server is really eating up your ram.  You can always stop it after so many times, and that might reclaim the RAM.  That might be it, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: To add the project to IIS, go into the project's properties, and in the first tab, look for a button that says create directory down towards the bottom.  Clicking it adds the project to IIS, as long as that radio button near it is enabled.